# Is assignment in automatic reference counting systems thread-safe?

Tags: c++, swift, multithreading, vala, reference-counting

Languages like Swift, Vala and C++ (through shared_ptr) manage memory by reference counting. As far as i know updates to the reference count in these systems are performed atomically and thus thread-safe.

However, each time a reference/pointer is reassigned, the former referenced object needs a reference count decrement, the newly referenced object a reference increment, and finally the reference itself must be reassigned. So if the same reference is accessible from multiple threads (i.e. through a global variable) and is reassigned by multiple threads at the same time, reference counts might become garbled.

So do C++ shared pointers, Vala references, Swift references take steps to avoid such problems? If not what steps are necessary in each of the three languages to make such access safe?

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If reference counting wasn't thread safe then reference counting would be a useless feature.

Comment: @rmaddy: true, but like I say in the first paragraph: reference count updates are already thread safe. What I'm asking about is the special corner case where **the exactly same** reference/pointer is reassigned by multiple threads, i.e. when reassigning a global variable or through a shared_ptr& in C++

Answer (score 4):

see the last paragraph of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

A `shared_ptr` ***variable*** is not thread safe and shouldn't be accessed from multiple threads if one or more threads modify the ***variable***. Multiple variables managing the same pointer are atomic and each thread is free to modify its own copy of the `shared_ptr`.

For example this is not safe:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr< std::string > str( new std::string() );
    std::vector< std::thread > threads;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]
        {
            if ( str->empty() )
            {
                str.reset( new std::string( "thread string" ) );
            }
            else
            {
                str.reset();
            }
        });
    }
    for ( auto& thread : threads )
    {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

but this is as the threads don't modify the `str` variable but do increase its reference count:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr< std::string > str( new std::string() );
    std::vector< std::thread > threads;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]
        {
            std::shared_ptr< std::string > str2 = str;
            if ( str2->empty() )
            {
                str2.reset( new std::string( "thread string" ) );
            }
            else
            {
                str2.reset();
            }
        });
    }
    for ( auto& thread : threads )
    {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

C++20 adds `std::atomic_shared_ptr` which is completely thread safe. Before that you can use the atomic non member functions.

Comment: Ah, so in C++ shared_ptr assignment is not thread-safe, but we can use atomic_shared_ptr to make it thread-safe. What about Swift and Vala?

Comment: @Aiueiia I assume they are similar but this will be stated in their documentation.

Comment: For Vala: g_object_ref and g_object_unref are called in the generated C code which use g_atomic_int_add () and friends, see the source code here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/blob/master/gobject/gobject.c#L3215

Comment: This is documented here: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Atomic-Operations.html#glib-Atomic-Operations.description

Comment: @Aiueiia _Copy_ assignment is perfectly safe.  It says so - explicitly - in the quote in Alan's answer.  Is that what you mean?  I notice that some overloads of `operator=` are not copy assign.  Those, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), are not threadsafe.

Comment: @Jens: I forgot I can inspect the Vala-generated C code. It looks like setting a global (or any) reference in Vala will generate a call to g_object_unref, followed by an assignment. Thus the behaviour is the same as with a shared_ptr in C++: Reference-count updates are thread-safe as long as multiple threads do not assign to the same reference. Otherwise, all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

Reference counting is threadsafe in Swift, because the underlying [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject?changes=_5&language=objc) is threadsafe.  In that case the reference count is an inherent property of the the object itself so your question is moot.  It looks like the same is true of Vala.

Which leaves C++, always late to the ball.

`std::shared_ptr`'s implementation of *reference counting* is threadsafe, as the quote in Alan's post makes clear, but telling one to start looking after a different object apparently is not.

It is not common to do this.  That rather undermines it's purpose, certainly if you're trying it make your code threadsafe.  More details at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) - some of those overloads of `operator=` are threadsafe and some are not.